# Sales representative salary. What is the meaning of base salary with comission percentage

Tags: salary, job-offer, software, france

I am a 42 years old french man. I could be interested in working abroad. Today I was contacted by the human resources manager of a big company. She wanted to offer me:

- 34 k base with 60% commission . What does it means?
- I would be  grateful if someone could explain me that salary.

60% commission is included in the 34 K?

In France we haven't got the same process, I would like get more information about it please.

Comment: It means that you have a 34K base salary (that you will always get), plus 60% of commissions of whatever it is that you manage to sell or whatever (say you sold 1000 Euros, you get 60% of them as comissions).

Answer (score 5):

You need to clarify with HR.

34 base with 60% commission could mean several things Most likely one of these:

1. 60% commission with a guarantee of 34K and sales over that at 60%, so at about 57K in sales, you'd start to get paid past the 34
2. 34 base PLUS 60% of all sales, in which case all sales would be added to the 34 base

Call HR and clarify what it means at their company

Comment: +1 to this. Also, don't rely on people on the internet to tell you what your salary is likely to be. Ask the people you're going to be working for :-)

Comment: @Richard I've got to trust someone with a name like yours.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked several sales positions in the US that provided salary and 2 that had a guaranteed base.  At those 2 positions it worked like this:

You have a base of 1300ish every 2 weeks.  For that 2 weeks of work if your 60% Commission > 1300 then your gross pay will be 60% of your total sales.  Otherwise it will be 1300.

There is also a 90 day probation period.  During that time you are paid only the base pay.  Your commissions accrue as potential earnings, but if you are terminated before the end of probation you lose those commissions.  If after 90 days you do not meet their expectations which is usually at least 50% above the minimum to meet the base pay for those 90 days then they terminate you, and you do not get any extra commission(yes even if you would normally be owed it).  If you do meet it that commission is held as a reserve in case you fall below the 1300 for a 2 week period.

In theory when you leave the Job if there is a remaining balance on your reserve then they are supposed to pay it out.  My experience at the one I lasted 9 months was that they threw fees, and cost reimbursements etc on that amount that resulted in a check of a few hundred dollars instead of the several thousand it should have been.  I have heard from many others similar stories at other companies.

Of course the exact implementation of that policy varies by company and some companies are probably less shady than others.  But in general my experience in sales was it was a feast or famine experience.  When you are doing well they will throw bonuses and perks like they are candy.  Have a hard month or two and you are out, and that nest egg your thought was waiting for you got eaten up by the taxes and costs of those "Perks" they gave you when it was all going well.

And if you needed 19500 to get out of probation but only hit 19499... they will let you go just because they can keep that extra 3900 in commissions by doing it.